# how to redirect from my application to an other application such as facebook android studio?

Tags: android

I wanna know can I redirect my application to another application, I am using android studio and i am a biginner, I searched a solution but I did not find.
i want to to redirect my application to another which control my ip camera

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you should use intents https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.targetapp");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, "com.package.yourapp" should be the target app's package, not your app.

Comment: Exactly, I'll rename it to avoid confusion. Thank you

Comment: if i wanna redirect to facebook what i have to di in package ?